# How can I match everything not in a character set with regex and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to **exclude everything except** [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9] and [~!#$].

```
if( $("#name").val().test(/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!#$]/)) {
    alert("Disallowed character used.");
    return false;
}
```

I thought test would return true if it finds a match and that because I included the caret symbol it should match everything that is not in my expression.

However input such as this works: jAcK%%$21#x

When it shouldn't work because it has symbols I'm trying to disallow.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `match` instead of `test`, since test is function of `RegExp` instead of `String`

```
var hasBadInput = !!"jAcK%%$21#x".match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!#$]/) //true
```

Or reverse the position

```
(/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!#$]/).test("jAcK%%$21#x") //returns true
```

Comment: i have never seen any `!!` at javascript before...is this `not not true` logic?

Comment: @aswzen It coerces a value to its boolean equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

[`Regexp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) should be called on the regex.

```js
var $name = $("#name");

$name.on("keyup", function(e) {

    if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!#$]/.test($name.val())) {
      console.log("Nope");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("Good");
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" >
```